# Error when i run app from android studio

Tags: android, gradle

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim.class

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are including the appCompat v7 library more then once. You may need to do a replace in your manifest page to avoid this issue.

For example you can override the gms version like this

You may need to do the equivelent for appcompat or find out which libraries are including it. Consider setting their transitives = false to avoid pulling it in muliple times.

Also view your dependency tree to see where/what dependencies are being overwritten at compile time.

This could also be a propagated error because of duplicated JAR files in your libs directory that are also in your Gradle dependency section.

But basically you have a duplicated dependency.